# NullPointerException when add a views dynamically (Context?)

Tags: android, view, android-context

I'm trying to add and modify some text in a layout inside of another layout.

I'm trying to do it by calling the next method, but it crashed when it tries to modify the text of `tv_event_hour`.

The line: `tv_event_hour.setText(getHour(timestamp) + " - ");`

What is the problem?

```
public void addInputDescription(int timestamp, String description)
    {
        LinearLayout mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.event_container);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View mChildView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_event_day_header, mRootLayout, false);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mRootLayout.addView(mChildView, params);

        TextView tv_event_hour = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_hour);
        TextView tv_event_message = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_message);

        tv_event_hour.setText(getHour(timestamp) + " - ");
        tv_event_message.setText(description);
    }

public String getHour(long timeStamp){
    Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(df);
}
```

Comment: Does your `program_event_day_header` layout have a view with id `tv_event_hour`? What's the exact stacktrace of the NPE?

Comment: can you post also getHour?

Comment: can you post LogCat?

Comment: Either you don't have a tv_event_hour id in your layout and so your TextView is null, or the crash occurs in getHour. Set a breakpoint at this line: TextView tv_event_hour = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_hour); make one step and check if tv_event_hour is null.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I make a mistake, I was calling R.layout.program_event_day_header, but the right XML was R.layout.program_event_day_input.